# I felt that there was not a second "to be" lost of this contact

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Normally, when you come up against a rare wild animal in Africa, you
> grab your binoculars or your camera at once.
>
> It is a simple reflex action. This gorilla was thirty yards away and
> divided from us by tangled undergrowth and might not perhaps have made
> a very good photograph, but we could certainly have seen him more
> clearly through glasses.
>
> Yet none of us moved. In my own case (and I suspect in the case of my
> friend as well) **I felt that there was not a second to be lost of this
> contact**, not even the few instants required to put the binoculars to
> my eyes.

What does the line in bold mean? The sentence contains "to be", so I wonder, was there a second that had been lost of the contact or not?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in bold means that they did not want to lose a single moment of the experience even for a few seconds. They used this sentence to describe the excitement of the character(s).

Comment: Wait, are you banned?